# Как пройти форму авторизации на сайте с помощью Python?

Tags: python, веб-программирование, авторизация

Я являюсь новичком в Python, и пока не очень хорошо разбираюсь в вебе.

Расскажите, пожалуйста, как проходить авторизацию в такой форме с помощью Python?
Я пытался отследить, какие файлы cookie передаются в момент авторизации и передать их через selenium, но получил ошибку selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidCookieDomainException: Message: invalid cookie domain при том, что все данные cookie верны (я отслеживал их автоматически командой `driver.get_cookies()`).

```
def authorise():
driver = webdriver.ChromiumEdge()
driver.get(url)
cookies = [{'domain': domain, 'httpOnly': True, 'name': name, 'path': '/', 'secure': True, 'value': value}]
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

Возможно, нужно как-то взаимодействовать с самим браузером?

[image: Скриншот формы авторизации на сайте]

Comment: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/browser/cookies/

Comment: Я уже читал документацию к этой функции до написания вопроса здесь, спасибо. Хотелось бы получить несколько более развернутый ответ, верна ли моя логика с файлами cookie в принципе и, если нет, то как это должно работать?

Comment: С cookies = {'domain': domain, 'httpOnly': True, 'name': name, 'path': '/', 'secure': True, 'value': value} результат тот же, т. к. как я уже писал, изначальный цикл дает то же) Короче говоря, в данном участке ошибки нет, все передается в соответствии с документацией, но этот метод не рабочий. Меня интересует, как реализуется прохождение подобных окон: работает ли в данном случае в принципе передача файлов cookie, и есть ли какой-либо другой способ взаимодействия с ним (как самостоятельным окном, например, или лучше пытаться через get- и post-запросы)?

Comment: пытаться get- и post-запросы в рамка одной сессий.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашел подходящий вариант решения в другом похожем вопросе на Stackoverflow ([оригинал](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999565/python-https-get-with-basic-authentication))

Аутентификацию через подобное окно можно пройти, передав логин и пароль вместе со ссылкой методу get библиотеки requests:

```
import requests
r = requests.get(url, auth=('myusername', 'mybasicpass'))
print(r.text)
```

UPD: или же, если принципиально, чтобы ссылка открылась именно в selenium, можно передать логин и пароль прямо внутри URL:

```
http://username:password@www.example.com/
```